# In SQL how do I throw an error when updating 'not null' values in a database table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Looking to throw an error where the value i'm updating is a 'not null' value.

For example. In below table, say I wanted to update Paul's lastname with 'Jackson'. The SQL should throw an error to say that the value that is being updated is 'not null'.

> **First Lastname**
>  Paul Parkinson
>  Peter null
>  Turkey null

As a second part to this question, I'm actually looking to do this in the APEX Express Data Load Wizard. If anyone would know how to modify the update command to do this, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Define a [NOT NULL constraint at table level for that column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394596/how-to-add-a-not-null-constraint-on-column-containing-null-values)

Comment: Either add `AND LastName Is NOT NULL` to your update (this wont throw an error, it just own't update) or add an UPDATE trigger (this will affect insert/update/delete performance)

Comment: Maybe you could use a before update trigger on a certain column. If :NEW.Value is NOT NULL raise an exception.

Comment: @Tenzin, NOT NULL or new.lastname <> old.lastname?

Comment: @jarlh Topic starts question now is the he wold like the lastname to stay NULL. If you do :NEW.LastName <> :OLD.LastName the if the entry already would be 'McJack' you can update to 'McEllen', and then the entry is still not NULL.

Comment: @Tenzin, what I meant was perhaps the trigger should allow to set Paul Parkinson's lastname to Parkinson, even though he already has a lastname.

Comment: @Tenzin thanks for that. I'm a newbie. Would an update trigger , throw an error, when the update tries to commit the data to the db and finds that the column is 'not null' ? Do you know what the command will look like.... Another way to look at it is, Only update records where the value is 'null' otherwise throw an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this with a trigger.  Example trigger:

```
create trigger schema.trigger_name
    before update of last_name
    on tablename
    for each row
begin
    if :old.last_name is not null then
        raise_application_error (-20100, 'Last name already has a value');
    end if;
end;
/
```

But this will stop any process that is running by raising a plsql error.

Comment: thank you so much, I've tested this and it works perfectly. Just a question, if I wanted to throw a warning message instead of an application error, is this possible?

Comment: You could pipe a warning to dbms_output.  Then make sure its being run in an sql editor that supports dbms_output.  Or PLSQL region in apex,  then you would use htp.prn.
Example to use instead of raise_application_error:
    dbms_output.put_line ('Warning: ' || :old.last_name || ' changed to ' || :new.last_name);
    htp.prn ('Warning: ' || :old.last_name || ' changed to ' || :new.last_name);

Comment: thanks Olafur. Sorry to ask,I'm very new to APEX, I want to be able to output this when the updates run in the Oracle APEX Data Load Wizard. It seems the trigger runs when the updates occur, but not sure how to get APEX to display the htp warning message to the end-user when they do the upload of the csv file.

Comment: Personally I would create a temp warning table. Make the trigger insert into that table. Then output the content of that table after the loading is finished

Comment: thanks @Olafur, thats a good suggestion. I created the new table and insert it now into the table, but now I'm struggling to output the content to the user. I've been able to find that the values are stored within a APEX collection of arrays under C01 at the end of the data load wizard. I've posted a question about it at [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32930072/how-to-access-an-element-inside-an-array. Would you mind taking a look?

Comment: Note that this solution will stop any no-change update (e.g. if a process tries to update the entire row, it will fail even if it didn't change the value).