# Apex_Collections - How do I loop through an apex collection of arrays

Tags: sql, database, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a collection of array's, currently the code

```
select apex_collections.c001 from apex_collections where collection_name = 'LOAD_CONTENT'
```

Shows the below on screen.

> **C001**
>
> 570
>
> 571

I have another table called errorTable that has a column Table1ID that matches with the values contained within the C001 array. I need to display all the records within the errorTable to the user where there is a match. In this example I want to show all records in errorTable where Table1ID match '570' or '571'.

I'm thinking I need to do a loop through the apex_collections C001 array and then do something like select * from errorTable where apex_collections.c001(i) = errorTable.Table1ID

I'm trying to get help on how to write this loop as I'm struggling a bit with that.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You've put data in a collection and now you want to access it. Great, you've shown how to do that. What do you want to do with it? Where is it meant to go or what is happen to it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've edited the question to try and make it more clear. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new region. Type: "PL/SQL Dynamic Content".

In the part for "PL/SQL Code".  Put in something like:

```
begin
    htp.prn ('<b>Rows with errors:</b><br><br>');

    for i in (select errortable.*
                from errortable, apex_collections
               where apex_collections.c001 (i) = errortable.table1id 
                and apex_collections.collection_name = 'LOAD_CONTENT') loop
        htp.prn (i.column1 || '<br>');
    end loop;
end;
```

This join makes sure that only records from **apex_collections** are shown that have a matching entry in **errortable**

You can also simply create a report region (classic/interactive) and use the SQL as source:

```
select errortable.*
  from errortable, apex_collections
 where apex_collections.c001 (i) = errortable.table1id 
  and apex_collections.collection_name = 'LOAD_CONTENT'
```

Comment: Why would you recommend a PLSQL region? This is perfectly fine report material.

Comment: That's right,  just put a plsql region as an alternative.  Will update answer.  I knew from the posters previous question that this is a notification region from data load ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904466/in-sql-how-do-i-throw-an-error-when-updating-not-null-values-in-a-database-tab/32905275#32905275 )

Comment: Still seems like OP is running with his head into a wall. Honestly, I think the linked Q is marked answered though it really isn't. The solution is this question: check the content to load vs that in the database and report the rows which will be invalid. It's a wizard, so adding this error report / step in is easiest by using a report. Personally, I don't see how a notification region serves use, but ok.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following:
`select apex_collections.c001 from apex_collections apex inner join errorTable errors on apex.c001 = errors.Table1ID where apex.collection_name = 'LOAD_CONTENT'`

`inner join` will give you only records from errorTable that match the values contained in the C001 column

Please take a look at the [specification of Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for more info regarding INNER JOINs

Comment: thanks for reply. Tried your code and also tried **SELECT *
FROM errortable e
    INNER JOIN apex_collections c
    ON e.table1id = c.c001
WHERE collection_name = 'LOAD_CONTENT'** Can't seem to get it too work

Comment: You made sure that `errortable` contains data with `table1id in ('570', '571')`? Also `c001` and `table1id` both have the same data type?
If Yes - please provide actual result of your query as well as records from errortable and apex_collections tables that you want to join.

Comment: @AlexKondrashov while the syntax is correct, your doc link goes to microsoft, while OP is working with oracle. And c001 is a varchar2 column, while the table id is likely number. It shouldn't really be an issue though.

Comment: @Tikkaty where are you running your select? Is has to be in the same session as the one which holds the collection. You can't run this query in your sql developer or anything. Where are you using it? Try creating a report on it.