# How to make a NULLable column to NOT NULL in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, null, constraints

How to make a NULLable column (varchar2(20)) to NOT NULL of a table in oracle where I have more than 1 million records in the table

Comment: There is already an answer for that.
Check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394596/how-to-add-a-not-null-constraint-on-column-containing-null-values)

Answer (score 7):

**NOT NULL** constraint specifies that a column cannot contain NULL values. To add a NOT NULL constraint to an existing table by using the **ALTER TABLE** statement.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY ( column_name NOT NULL);
```

In this case, the column_name must not contain any NULL value before applying the NOT NULL constraint.